# How do I apply my customized mails table to all folders in Thunderbird 78?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I customized my mails table by reordering the columns, removing columns (Read status, Junk status, Thread) and changing the order to date (newest at top instead of oldest at top).

Then I switched to another folder and noticed it's the default table again with all columns I've hidden and newest mails at bottom.

I am on Mozilla Thunderbird 78.7.1 build 20210203182138, Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon.

**How can I apply my customized mail table to all folders of all mail accounts?**

Comment: AFAIK, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Though there are [add-ons to change the default layout](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/set-default-columns/) of columns and sort order, it is easy to [apply the the layout of one account to that of another](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/message-list-columns).

In the row of column header, click on the small "table" icon on the far right and select the last choice, *Apply columns to...".

[image: Copy column layout in Thunderbird]

BTW, there is a new, *beta* version of [Columns Wizard](https://github.com/micz/ColumnsWizard/issues/95), endeavoring to be Thunderbird v. 78-compatible, but it appears to have languished since 2020.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't install, because I am on Thunderbird 78 and the highest supported version of this plugin is Thunderbird 60.